# The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0. problem flutter on build apk

Tags: flutter

i am trying to get the apk for my flutter app on
``à
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-arm64, locale es-419)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.81.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources ```

and i got this error not sure how to fix it.

```
    ivan@MacBook-Air-de-Ivan flutterapp % flutter build apk --release
    Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
    Font asset "fa-brands-400.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 187208 to 2728 bytes (98.5% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
    Font asset "fa-solid-900.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 394628 to 1176 bytes (99.7% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
    Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 1480 bytes (99.9% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
    e: /Users/ivan/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c4988ff80110f75080a936fc6f044848/transformed/core-1.10.1/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
    e: /Users/ivan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-jvm/1.6.0/a7257339a052df0f91433cf9651231bbb802b502/annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
    e: /Users/ivan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
    e: /Users/ivan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
    e: /Users/ivan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.22/636bf8b320e7627482771bbac9ed7246773c02bd/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
    e: /Users/ivan/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.8.22/1a8e3601703ae14bb58757ea6b2d8e8e5935a586/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
    Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           44.1s
    ✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk (19.4MB).
    ivanvilches@MacBook-Air-de-Ivan flutterapp %
```

thanks you for any help